# What is the character set of hash when md5 is used with salt using crypt()?

Tags: php

What is the **character set** of the `output` given by `crypt() using md5` with salt.

By hash, I mean just the `22` characters after **"$1$ "8 random characters"$ "**. So I wanted to know what type of characters does **22 hashed character contains**?

Comment: Since it is a binary array output, you can encode that (Base64) into any encoding you want, e.g. UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this and have found a few questions that touched on this but nobody seems to have a definitive answer, nobody except the code of course and, this python implementation of the same:

http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.md5_crypt.html

Based on this, it seems both the salt, and the hash itself are encoded with the following regex char set: [./0-9A-Za-z]

I would expect these to output the same since they are all trying to be compatible with the same shadow password utilities.